# Local svn copy disconnected from repo

Tags: svn, onedrive

I had to "upgrade" to MS OneDrive at work, and after doing so, my local working copies of subversion repo checkouts are not recognized by TortoiseSVN/AnkhSVN. I have local changes so it's not as simple as just redownloading from the server.  Is there something I can tweak behind the scenes or similar to get my existing copies recognized again by SVN?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the root cause - OneDrive does not play nice with SVN. After I moved the local working copies outside of my OneDrive hierarchy, TortoiseSVN & AnkhSVN had no problems recognizing the local files correctly.